# Declaring dynamic profile path in MsBuild

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

Currently I'm trying to copy a file to a location inside a user's profile, but hit a problem with declaring dynamic profile name, e.g.:

```
<Target Name="CopyScript">
    <MsBuild Projects="JsProject.csproj" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)\myScript.js" DestinationFolder="$(systemdrive)\Documents and Settings\$(userProfileName)" />
</Target>
```

What is the syntax for declaring a dynamic user profile name?  Do I have to get the profile name from somewhere, or is there another MsBuild task which will find it for me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to get this with the HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH env variables. For example:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="Demo" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <PropertyGroup>
  <UserDir>$(HOMEDRIVE)$(HOMEPATH)</UserDir>
 </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Demo">
 <Message Text="UserDir : $(UserDir)" Importance="High" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

When you execute the Demo target you should get the path to the current users home directory.

Comment: @ Sayed: I used your example, and it returned "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator".  If I only want it to return "Administrator", do I just use something like $(username)?

Comment: In that case you would use the env variable USERNAME so $(USERNAME)

Comment: you could also use `$(USERPROFILE)`, which would remove the need to concatenate `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH`.